# npm forever equivalent in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, ruby-on-rails-4, forever

With node, I can use `forever` to keep a process running forever. What's the most popular equivalent in rails?

I'm trying to avoid any overly complex or expensive setup right now so I'm really looking for a simple, cheap solution.

Comment: Are you looking for something to run processes in the background? You're probably looking for [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) or [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque). Both have great railscasts to get you started. [Sidekiq](http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq?view=asciicast). [Resque](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup [passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) and your rails app will run so long as apache is running.